# Is there a Python method to check whether a binary tree is a min heap?

Tags: python, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search, min-heap

How can I write a function that can accept a binary tree as a parameter and returns True  if it is a min heap and False if not.

```
from heapq import heapify

def binary_heap(tree):
  while len(tree) > 1:
    if heapify(tree):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: So... what's your question?

Comment: That's my approach and it seems it's not working.

Comment: `heapq` doesn't work on binary trees and `heapify` doesn't check whether or the input is a heap, it turns it into one, so of course this doesn't work. Do you know how what a heap is? How do you define the tree?

Comment: Yes, I do. Thank you for the feedback. How should I approach that question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a min heap has to satisfy, per `heapq`'s [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html):

> ```
> heap[k] <= heap[2*k+1] and heap[k] <= heap[2*k+2]
> ```

You can iterate through all child nodes to validate that they are greater than or equal to their parent nodes (note that `i - 1 >> 1` is a shorthand for `(i - 1) // 2` when `i > 0`):

```
def is_minheap(lst):
    return all(lst[i] >= lst[i - 1 >> 1] for i in range(1, len(lst)))
```

so that:

```
from heapq import heapify
from random import sample

lst = sample(range(10), 10)
print(is_minheap(lst), lst)
heapify(lst)
print(is_minheap(lst), lst)
```

outputs something like:

```
False [1, 2, 6, 8, 0, 5, 3, 9, 7, 4]
True [0, 1, 3, 7, 2, 5, 6, 9, 8, 4]
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/1uhd6c

Answer (score 0):

For a binary tree to be a min heap, it should satisfy this two condition:

1. tree should be complete binary tree
2. every node should be less than or equal to its children

And a simple implementation would be like this

```py
def is_min_heap(node,ind,total_nodes):
  if node is Node:
    return True
  if ind >= total_nodes:
    return False
  if node.left and node.val > node.left.val or node.right and node.val > node.right.val:
    return False
  return is_min_heap(node.left, 2 * ind + 1, total_nodes) and is_min_heap(node.right, 2 * ind + 2, total_nodes)
```